# Ruby `Array#delete`

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am defining a method that takes two arguments (an array and a string) and deletes the string from the array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def using_delete(instructors, x = "Steven") 
  instructors = ["Josh", "Steven", "Sophie", "Steven", "Amanda", "Steven"] 
  instructors.delete ("Steven")
  instructors 
end
```

A test requiring all instances of `"Steven"` to be deleted is not passing.

Comment: your code should probably look more like this https://repl.it/BkQv/0

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

You need to move the `instructors` assignment outside of the method, otherwise there's no point in allowing it as an argument. Also, delete using the `x` argument instead of hardcoding the value:

```
instructors = ["Josh", "Steven", "Sophie", "Steven", "Amanda", "Steven"] 

def using_delete(instructors, x="Steven") 
  instructors.delete x
  instructors 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the last line representing `return` value of the method can sometimes be confusing to look at.

```
def using_delete(...) 
   #...
   instructors  # looks weird sometimes
end
```

Personally, I would prefer that such statements have explicit return if it is preceded by other statements.  Even [Ruby Style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-explicit-return) seems to indicate that explicit return statement be avoided in methods with single line expression. *(Jury may be out whether that's what it really means - will have to wait for experienced Rubyists comments)*

```
def using_delete(...) 
   #...
   return instructors # looks nice, intention clear
end
```

---

Here is a version that can be used if you don't want to use `return` statement. It takes advantage of `tap` method:

```
def using_delete(instructors, x)
  instructors.tap { |i| i.delete (x) }
end

using_delete(["Josh", "Steven", "Sophie", "Steven", "Amanda", "Steven"], "Steven")
#=> ["Josh", "Sophie", "Amanda"]
```

---

On lighter note, not sure what is your use case, but having a default value of `"Steven"` for `x` is not a good idea - as it makes `"Steven"` looks like a very bad instructor.  Typically defaults are used for defaults that really make sense.  For example:

```
def increment(num, by = 1)
  num + by
end

increment(5)  # increment 1 by default
#=> 6  
increment(10, 6) # unless increment value is specified explicitly
#=> 16
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 def using_delete(instructors, x="Steven")
 instructors.delete(x)
 puts instructors
 end
```

Also will delete any other name you wish to delete instead of "Steven", lets say you wanted to delete "Amanda"

```
 using_delete(["Josh", "Steven", "Sophie", "Steven", "Amanda", "Steven"],"Amanda")
```

Josh
Steven
Sophie
Steven
Steven

will delete any element "Steven" in any array parameter you put inside method.

```
using_delete(["Josh", "Steven", "Sophie", "Steven", "Amanda","Steven"])
```

Josh
Sophie
Amanda

I hope that explanation helped. I'm also a noob.  Good luck.

Comment: Please work on your formatting. You can find information for using MarkDown in [the site help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Will do @theTinMan, thanks for the constructive criticism.